# JAVA ANDROID - get list files of a folder

Tags: java, android, list, directory

I want to display images of different folders in a `GridView`, but I don't know what I need to do for get a list with the name of files that are inside a folder in drawable.

Comment: Is Google down again?  Sheesh

Comment: what? exist another forum better for android developers?

Comment: Yes, Google. http://bit.ly/1iNmAYs.  Or search here, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+get+list+of+files+in+directory.  Please always search before asking, especially for simple questions.

Answer (score 9):

this method will give you a list containing a list of dir folders and also sub folders:

```
public void listf(String directoryName, ArrayList<File> files) {
File directory = new File(directoryName);

// get all the files from a directory
File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
for (File file : fList) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        files.add(file);
    } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
        listf(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I see this in another post, but how i can put de directory "drawable" that is in the project?

Comment: your dir must be something like this: `res/drawable`

Answer (score 0):

First Wirte this method in AsyncTask class.

```
private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
        ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                if(file.getName().toString().toLowerCase().contains(fileNameToSearch.toLowerCase()) || file.getName().toString().toUpperCase().contains(fileNameToSearch.toUpperCase())){
                    inFiles.add(file);
                }else {
                    inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
                }
            } else {
                if(file.getName().toString().toLowerCase().contains(fileNameToSearch.toLowerCase()) || file.getName().toString().toUpperCase().contains(fileNameToSearch.toUpperCase())){
                    inFiles.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        return inFiles;
    }
```

Call this method from `doInBackground(...)`

```
List<File> files = getListFiles(new File(directoryPath));
```