# Making a GridView take images from a specific folder

Tags: android, image, gridview, uri, listadapter

I am a newbie to android app making and I am still a beginner with a little knowledge . I have been trying to make an android app that works like a gallery , but it only displays images under a specific folder. For the UI , I am starting with only a `GridView` (or `TwoWayGridView` which is derived from the latter) , and have been trying to let this `GridView` take its contents from this folder .

I have made this folder and copied an image to it for testing and failed. No image was displayed .Plus I am not very familiar with `Cursors` and `ListAdapters` . Somethings that I'm sure that are correct are permissions , manifest , and layout of the activity.Moreover , I believe my problem is around `URI`s . Please check my code below :

**Some namings:**

```
Uri contentUri;

Cursor mImageCursor;
TwoWayGridView mImageGrid;
ListAdapter mAdapter;

String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

**onCreate method :**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        File motherDirectory = new File(sdCard+"/Favory");
        if(!motherDirectory.exists()){
            motherDirectory.mkdir();
        }


        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{motherDirectory.getAbsolutePath()}   ,null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                contentUri = uri ;
                initGrid(uri);
            }
        });



    }
```

**initGrid(Uri) method :**

```
private void initGrid(Uri folderUri) {



mImageCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(folderUri,
        ImageThumbnailAdapter.IMAGE_PROJECTION, null, null,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
mImageGrid = (TwoWayGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
mAdapter = new ImageThumbnailAdapter(this, mImageCursor);
mImageGrid.setAdapter(mAdapter);

mImageGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(TwoWayAdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i(TAG, "showing image: " + mImageCursor.getString(ImageThumbnailAdapter.IMAGE_NAME_COLUMN));
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

Thanks for your help , and please if there is an easier alternative way of doing this tell me, I care for the results more than the methods now . If you need anything or any more information please tell me in the comments below . Thanks again !

Answer (score 4):

To Read the Files of a folder you can use this function ( from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457947/java-android-get-list-files-of-a-folder) post ):

```
String directoryName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/YourFolder/";

public ArrayList<File> listf(String directoryName, ArrayList<File> files) {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);

    // get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList) {
        Log.e("path : ","  "+file);
        if (file.isFile()) {
            files.add(file);
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listf(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

Then you should load this list of files to your GridView Adapter, i suggest you use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

You just give your file path and Adapter ImageVIew at that position

```
loadImageUtil.loadBitmapToImageView(imageView, youArrayList.get(position));
```

For more informations how to use this library you can see examples, there is an example with grid view gridView

Comment: Is this method recursive ?