# Looking for an upload file type of structure used in HTML (PHP) for Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, file, upload

Looking for an upload file type of structure used in HTML for Android (Java)
The HTML + PHP version can be seen in the following link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Do we have something like this for Android (Java)?

Answer (score 0):

yes u can upload file to server using php as a backend all u need to do is to use the httpmultipart lib for uploading the files. Go apache's website and download the latest http multipart lib and add it to ur project. create a php page and u don't need html page if u are uploading it from android.

use http client for making request. but please make sure which method u r using to upload file to ur server.
 if u are using post request for uploading from android then u must use $_post method in php and if u r using get method u must use $_get method in ur php page. otherwise it will jot work.

Comment: Dear Friend, Thank you for your answer.I am building an application for chess. After the program launches ** I need to code a scenario where the user enters the android device folder system and looks for a file to load into the program ** Once the file is loaded into the program the rest of the project will take place. I have to do it with Java based in Android. Can you help with this? Regards, Aziz

Comment: which file it will load .I mean what type of file txt file or what?

Comment: Hello It will be a PGN file (portable game notation). But now after research I have found out that you don't need to load the file all you have to do is read it after you find where it is in the folder system. From this aspect I realize that I need a code that enables me to walk through the android devices folder system and list the files (with whatever extension it may have) until the user reaches the PGN file that he/she wants. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457947/java-android-get-list-files-of-a-folder) will solve most of my problems. Pls add your comments will be appreciated